# Angular / Electron using the renderer.js with angular components

Tags: angular, typescript, electron, angular-cli, angular6

I have created an angular 6 project using the angular-cli.

Following that that I have installed Electron and done this:

1. changed src/index.html base to
2. Installed Electron locally:

   npm install electron --save-dev
3. Created a main.js file on the root of my project

   const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

   let win;

   function createWindow () {
     win = new BrowserWindow({
       width: 600, 
       height: 600,
     })

   win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/myproject/index.html`)

   win.on('closed', function () {
       win = null
     })
   }

   app.on('ready', createWindow)

   app.on('window-all-closed', function () {

   if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
       app.quit()
     }
   })

   app.on('activate', function () {
     if (win === null) {
       createWindow()
     }
   })
4. Adjusted the package.json file

   {
     "name": "angular-electron",
     "version": "0.0.0",
     "license": "MIT",
     "main": "main.js", // <-- update here
     "scripts": {
       "ng": "ng",
       "start": "ng serve",
       "build": "ng build",
       "test": "ng test",
       "lint": "ng lint",
       "e2e": "ng e2e",
       "electron": "electron .", // <-- run electron 
       "electron-build": "ng build --prod && electron ." // <-- build app, then run electron 
     },
     // ...omitted
   }

If I now run

```
npm run electron-build
```

The project will work.

My problem now is that I have created a renderer.js file and want to execute functions there from my angular component

For example:

**renderer.js**

```
function somefunction() {
    // do something
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<button (click)="somefunction()">Run Function in renderer.js</button>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for **renderer.js** since you are using angular.You should add your function inside **app.component.ts**.

Having said that if you still need renderer.js, did you add the file to your index.html

```
  require('./somePath/dist/renderer.js')
```

This will make it globally accessible .